# How to change language in CardInput Widget's hint text(Stripe)

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I have implement stripe payment in my android app.I have use stripe's CardInput widget for card details.So I want to change language of CardInput Widget's hint text according to my app language.Is this is possible in stripe?If any one have idea about it please help me.

Comment: As far as I know it should just localise automatically if you change the language in the device settings in Android, the SDK has localised strings for the hints in the inputs.

Comment: @karllekko thanks for the answer.but i don't want to change device language.